# Install ubuntu 18.04 on ASUS zehpyrus GU502

Tags: 18.04, laptop, asus

I am trying to install ubuntu 18.04 on my asus zephyrus laptop.
I disabled secure boot and fast boot however the usb boot disk doesn't recognize the hard drive.
Changing SATA mode from Intel RST premium to AHCI disabled Windows from booting.
Anyone had experience installing ubuntu 18.04 on this laptop?
Any comments would much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+and+RST+site:askubuntu.com has the collective experience of those who have tried to make it work.

Comment: https://davidvielmetter.com/tricks/installing-ubuntu-dual-boot-on-a-dell-precision-which-already-runs-windows-10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully installed unbuntu 18.04 with wubi,just disabled secure boot and changed into AHCI.But i can only run ubuntu with AHCI and it disabled Windows form booting too.

Update:You can turn to AHCI and boot windows with safety mode.Windows will self check and it can run in AHCI too.

Comment: If you change your boot mode from IDE to AHCI, your Windows installation will get useless. But if you're installing Windows with IDE mode, too, you would be able to use both. Changing from ACPI to IDE made your Windows installation useless, but using IDE setting at the install time of Windows would make it usuable parallel to Ubuntu.